# Add specific rows from xlsx file to list using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to add some rows of xlsx files to an open list, but cannot figure out how to do so.
I have several xlsx files with data like this:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
1   A10   2        A10   2             AB
2   A105  1        A105  2             AB  
....
10  A250  4        A250  4             AB
```

I want the rows where the sum of cell value of column E minus the cell value of column B is not equal to zero to be added to the list. So in the example above, I only want the second row to be added to the list, as 2 - 1 is 1 and not zero. So the list should contain this afterwards:

```
  A105  1    A105  2   AB
```

I do not know how to make this happen and have tried a couple of things, both with pandas and with openpyxl, but I have not gotten it right yet. Can anyone help me along the way?

Here is the start of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

numbers = []
rapp = r"C:\Myfolder
files = glob.glob(rapp)
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(excelfile)
    if df.iloc[:,4] - df.iloc[:,1] != 0:   #I get an errormessage on this, and do not know how to express this properly.
        numbers =     #I do not know what to write here either, as I somehow need it to be row.tolist()

Traceback:
if df.iloc[:,4] - df.iloc[:,1] != 0:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in pandas working with arrays, not with scalars.

Output of comparing is:

```
print ((df.iloc[:, 4] - df.iloc[:, 1]) != 0)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

There are 2 `False`s and one `True`.

And cannot use `if`, because python is `confused` - there are `True` and `False`s - what is output?

You can first compare column `E` and `B`, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select columns and output get to list:

```
m = df['E'].ne(df['B'])
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Solution with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
m = df.iloc[:, 4].ne(df.iloc[:, 1])
pos = [0,1,3,7]
print (df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist())
[['A105', 1, 'A105', 'AB']]
```

Edited your solution:

```
m = (df.iloc[:, 4] - df.iloc[:, 1]) != 0
pos = [0,1,3,7]
print (df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist())
[['A105', 1, 'A105', 'AB']]
```

Solution for multiple columns:

```
print (df)
      A  B   C     D  E   F   G   H
0   A10  2 NaN   A10  2 NaN NaN  AB
1   A10  3 NaN   A10  2 NaN NaN  AB
2  A105  1 NaN  A105  2 NaN NaN  AB
3  A250  4 NaN  A250  4 NaN NaN  AB

m = (df.iloc[:, 4] - df.iloc[:, 1]) != 0
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

pos = [0,1,3,7]
print (df.loc[m, df.columns[pos]].values.tolist())
[['A10', 3, 'A10', 'AB'], ['A105', 1, 'A105', 'AB']]
```

Comment: Now I understand more of boolean indexing, thank you so much! But this does not give me the entire row to the list, only the sum of column 4 - column 1.

Comment: I add solution with multiple no equal values -  so output is nested list. Is is OK?

Comment: Now that this is done, do you know how I am able to put the data back into an excel file? Where the columns are suggested by the commas and the rows by the brachets in the list?

Comment: I think [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) shoul work perfectly.